# SSH connection - hostkey

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I'm trying to make  a connection vis SSH using this code

```
#SSH conde for connection
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
# Load SSH host keys.
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
# Add SSH host key automatically if needed.
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(IP, username=USER, password=PSW,look_for_keys=False)
```

but somethimes a  message like the one in the picture occurrs:

[SSH_Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQ61l.png)

that gives me the error shown in picture:
[Hostkey_Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BOEe.png)

is there a way to avoid this message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BadHostKeyException](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/ssh_exception.html#paramiko.ssh_exception.BadHostKeyException) means that the SSH server's host key has changed, i.e. is different than the one you have stored (by default in `~/.ssh/known_hosts`).

Assuming you understand that this is bad practice in general (because you'll blindly accept host keys without verifying them), you can bypass host key verification by removing `load_system_host_keys()` and keeping `AutoAddPolicy`.

The reason it's not working for you is because `AutoAddPolicy` automatically adds host keys of **new** hosts, but since `load_system_host_keys()` is used the host you're connecting to is considered known (albeit with a changed key, hence the exception).